# how to get sum of a column in sharepoint 2013 list

Tags: workflow, jquery, calculated-column-formula

Not sure if i would get any answer from here.
I have a column number and title text.
The data would look like this:

```
Title  Paid
----------
Jacob  200
Patrick 100
Jacob   100
Patrick 300
```

What i would like to get is

```
Jacob: 300
Patrick 400
```

I was thinking of using a workflow and write the data to another list

Thanks in Advance if anyone has an idea

Comment: Where do you need this sum? In a custom web part or in a list view or others. also update the SharePoint version.

Answer (score 1):

- 2010/2013 No code: Set your view to Group By Title and Sum the Paid Column
- 2013 CSR (Client Side Rendering) code: Use`OnPreRender` to loop through the items
- 2010/2013 Calculated Column: [Sum Calculated Column (SP 2013)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159086/sum-calculated-column-sp-2013/159095#159095)

(Works in Group View)

[image]

Full explanation at: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/Create/Sum

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

SharePoint List: Find Sum, Average on the values with Group By
https://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/sharepoint-list-find-sum-average-on-the-values-with-group-by-3/

Answer (score 0):

**Client Side Rendering**

As DannyEngelman mentioned, you can use **CSR** for SharePoint 2013. Following snippet may help. I have tested it in `OnPreRender`

```
var newValues = [];

ctx.ListData.Row.forEach(function(item) {
    var isDuplicate = newValues.filter(v => v.Title == item.Title);
    if (isDuplicate.length == 0) {
        var hasSameTitle = ctx.ListData.Row.filter(v => v.Title == item.Title);
        var itemsSum = hasSameTitle.reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a["Paid."]) + parseFloat(b["Paid."]));
        item["Paid"] = itemsSum;
        newValues.push(item);
    }
});

ctx.ListData.Row = newValues;
```

[image]

**PS:** Not sure IE has support for [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) yet. If it does not have, then you can use `callback`.

Comment: How will i use prerender and onrender on this to apply the code ? it is not taking if i simply put the code as js and pass.